# Kubernetes not able to add label to pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am unable to add a label to my kubernetes pod. Why is this not working?

```
$ kubectl describe pods secure-monolith | grep Label
Labels:     app=monolith 

$ kubectl label pods secure-monolith "secure=enabled"
pod "secure-monolith" labeled

$ kubectl describe pods secure-monolith | grep Label
Labels:     app=monolith

$ kubectl label pods secure-monolith "secure=enabled"
'secure' already has a value (enabled), and --overwrite is false
```

As you can see, it says the label was successfully added, however the label does not appear when "describing" the pod; and it can also not be added again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grepping through the `describe` output, but only the first line of labels description contains `Label` string.

Labels output for two labels looks as follows:

```
Labels:         a=b
                c=d
```

So `secure=enabled` is there, you just filtered it out.

Comment: `grep -A 2` for the win ;)

Comment: @AntoineCotten: What if you have 4 labels? :)

Answer (score 2):

kubectl get pod **POD_NAME** --show-labels

This command shows all the labels added to the pod